# Why Can't I include this PHP file?

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

I have two PHP files in a directory.  One includes the other, `<?php include 'channels.phtml'; ?>`, and that works fine.  The problem arises when I move the included file to the parent directory and adjust the call, `<?php include '../channels.phtml'; ?>`.  In this case, the file is not found.

Why is it so?

I am using Ubuntu and I don't think it's a permission problem, but here's the details anyhow:

> parent directory: drwxrwxr-x  6 kim kim 4096 Mar 26 08:42 org
>
> child directory: drwxrwxr-x  2 kim kim 4096 Mar 26 08:47 profile
>
> included file: -rwxrwxrwx  1 kim kim   28 Mar 26 08:42 channels.phtml

I tried `require`, with the same result.

EDIT:

The fix put forward by mesutozer does indeed work, but it should not be required.  From the PHP manual entry on the include command:

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

Note that phpinfo shows that he current directory (.) is on the include path, and as far as I am aware I have not disabled relative paths.

FYI, I am using a ZF2.

Comment: Define `parent directory`.

Comment: You may have disabled relative paths in php.ini. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have current folder in your include path, or specify other file's full path as:

```
<?php include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../channels.phtml'; ?>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed!

Comment: Normally it shouldn't as default include path contains current directory ('.') like `include_path => .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`.